# Issue with CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run npm start for an Angular project but I'm getting this error and my attempt to Google-search the issue/solution wasn't successful. I'm using Angular CLI: 14.2.4

**npm start output**
[image]

Comment: Are you using CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in your code ? CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA comes from the package '@angular/core'

Comment: It's a project started by someone else 3 years ago but I'm not seeing anywhere this CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA was used.

Answer (score 2):

The `npm start` contains `ngx-admin@4.0.1 start`.
According to the [releases page](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/releases) of **ngx-admin**, it looks like you are 4 major versions behind, and the support for **Angular v14.x** came with **ngx-admin v8**.

Update `ngx-admin` or simply go to the [installation guidelines](https://akveo.github.io/ngx-admin/docs/getting-started/installation-guidelines) and follow the instructions.

#### Update

Since the project was started 3 years ago, you have to downgrade your Angular version to **Angular v9**, which I think was the one compatible with `ngx-admin@4.0.1`.

Comment: Tried to run  *ng serve* command alone so it won't run the ngx-admin first but the issue persisted

Comment: Did you update `ngx-admin`? Did you try a fresh installation to test compatibility? Did you downgrade your Angular version? if you did none, then of course it wouldn't work..

Comment: Hi Mohamed, the app was created by simply cloning ngx-admin and with my extensive Google-searching, there was no way to update it. So, the team is reviewing the idea of starting from scratch with React instead. Thanks for your support

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears in the production build only after upgrading to ionic 7, ;
eg
ionic build --prod;
or
ionic build --configuration="production"

For ionic serve and ng serve , ionic build / ng build  works fine;

compiling with for production with --prod; or --configuration="production" compresses app size and i am also stuck at this.